# Как сменить кодировку верхнего индекса из UTF-8 в windows-1251 на php?

Tags: php, кодировка

Прошу помощи у знатоков и гуру в PHP казалось бы банальном вопросе но....
Суть - по api мне прилетает значение в кодировке UTF-8 - мм².
Необходимо сменить кодировку на windows-1251.
Казалось бы нет ничего проще берем iconv и вперед, но нет iconv вообще ничего не возвращает (если ² убрать то норм меняет кодировку), что же мы не сдаемся берем второй метод mb_convert_encoding - в итоге получаем мм?.
Заменой знака вопроса на символ в нужной кодировке проблемы не решить так как там может быть не в квадрате а в кубе или градусы и т.п.
Помогите кто знает.

Comment: Если планируется вывод в html, то можно заранее заменить небезопасные символы на html-сущности, в том числе `²` → `&#178;` и уже потом менять кодировку. А так в кодировке windows-1251 символа ² действительно нету

Comment: Ну а лучше всего избавиться от необходимости менять кодировку, конечно

Comment: Как быть с градусами Цельсия, фиг знает, если бы речь шла только о цифрах - степенях, то исхитриться бы использовать тег <sup>...</sup>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Никак. В windows-1251 нет символа `²`.